# Unable to view the framework after archiving on Xcode 14.3

Tags: xcode

After Upgrading to Xcode 14.3 . I am unable to get the location of an archived framework on Mac. The framework archives and compiled successfully but when we try to view the archived framework by show Original it shows the error .

The alias “XYZ.framework” can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found.

However, everything works fine on Xcode 14.2 . We are able to get the location of archived framework on Xcode 14.2 by viewing show Original

I have already updated the cocoa pods version to 1.12.1

When we try to view the archived framework by show Original it shows the error .

The alias “XYZ.framework” can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found.